# use jquery dialog to confirm before submitting

Tags: jquery, forms, dialog, submit

I am using a form and I want to confirm before the form submits. Before I use confirm in javascript but now I want to replace it by dialog UI of jquery. I want that when user click on button "Valider" he has choice of submit form by clicking on submit or cancel. I am begginer in jQuery, this is my code, but I doesn't work.

```
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#valider').click(function(){
        $('#dialog').dialog({
            modal: true,
            buttons:{
            "submit":function(){
                document.form1.submit();
            },
            "cancel":function(){
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });

    });
        $('form#testconfirmJQ').submit(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#dialog').dialog('open');
        });

 });

</script>
<form action="test.php" method="post" name="form1">
    <input type="submit" name="valider" class="valider" id="valider" value="valider"/>
</form>
    <div id="dialog" title="Confirmation">
    </div>
</div>
```

When I click on "Valider" I have the dialog briefly, and the form is submitted. I am a bit confused about my code. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your jQuery is looking for `$('form#testconfirmJQ')`, so it's looking for a `form` with id `testconfirmJQ`. You don't have a form like that, so jQuery can't find the element. You could either remove the id from the code, so it looks like `$('form').submit(function(e){` or add the id to the form, so it looks like `<form action="test.php" id="testconfirmJQ" method="post" name="form1">`

Comment: No problem :) Glad I could help